# What's the best preposition to use after the word "possibility"

Tags: prepositions

What's the best preposition to use in this sentence:

Is there any possibility **of** you ensure my place?

Is there any possibility **to** you ensure my place?

Is there any possibility **of** you ensure my place?

Can I use the prepositions **of/to/you** after the word **possibility** in other cases?

tks in advance.

Comment: "Any possibility **for** you **to** ensure..." Other way to use "possibility": "any possibility **of** hav**ing** my place ensured by you..." or "any possibility of my place being ensure by you..." or even "any possibility of you ensuring my place..."

Comment: Third one is "ensured by you" not "ensure by you", among other possibilities.

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *of* with "possibility" this way:

> Is there any possibility of you ensur**ing** my place?

Note that you do *not* use the infinitive in this construction.

Note also that "to" is never used with "possibility," and "you" is *never* a preposition. I don't know where you got that notion.

You can use *for*, however, in a slightly different way:

> Is it possible for you to ensure my place?

Observe that I changed *possibility* to *possible* for that to work well.

**Full disclosure**: It *is* possible to use *to* if you use it with *possible*, as in the sentence you are reading right now.